# How to create extremely large vectors

Tags: memory-management

I want to store the intensity of each pixel of an image in a n*n matrix. I am currently storing it in a vector. But for extremely large dimensions the program crashes as it runs out of memory. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: @rohit Which language are you using?

Comment: @rohit be a bit more specific: what are extremely large dimensions? what datatype do you use to represent pixel intensities? what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your RAM is too small to hold all the information, you will need to use other means of storage. Maybe swapping to your harddisk. What kind of information is the intensity? A floating number? How many Pixels do your large images have? I think that your storage class simply creates too much overhead. Which language are you using? Can you supply some code snippets?

Comment: I will be needing it of float type..the dimensions will be of the form n^4 where n can take a value upto 1000